# Can not see dataset value in report builder preview

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created one dataset in my local machine

```
select
  ID,
  Mark, 
  dense_rank() over(order by Mark desc) as TopRank,
  dense_rank() over(order by Mark) as BottomRank
from cricket
  order by ID
```

When I setup dataset and datasouce in report builder and create one tablix report using all query columns but I can see only Mark value data in preview window and rest column are blank.

We can snap shot in attachment

[image].

When I print page button I can see all column value in page layout.

Can anyone help me out? to get all column values in preview mode

[image]

Comment: Reporting services can be... buggy. Have you tried all the usual stuff? Refresh your dataset on the "design" tab, close and reopen the builder, etc etc

Comment: @allmhuran:Thanks for comment..I have tried to create it many times even write it from scratch ..and same problem is coming with more reports also

Comment: Ouch. There are a few other threads on this site with various solutions, but there doesn't seem to be any "one right answer". Things like changing the font face or colour to hope it "resets" something, toggling the hidden flag on and off, resizing the row heights, and so on. Have you seen those threads?

Comment: Next to your report.rdl file is a cached data file, report.rdl.data, which is only used in preview mode. It sounds like it's still caching old data from a previous version of your data set when it had less columns in it.